# Separate .htaccess for folder, ignoring previous one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` in my root folder:

root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

So that incoming GET requests come through `http://www.example.com/somethingsomething` instead of `?page=somethingsomething`. That's all fine.

However, in the root folder I have another folder named `/i`. Id like this one to handle another type of request, which looks like this: `http://www.example.com/i/somethingsomething` with the ending actually meaning `http://www.example.com/i/index.php?img=somethingsomething`. Problem is that the `.htaccess` in the root folder is still in use. What I need is the following:

/i:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?img=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

, but somehow exclude the `.htaccess` in the root folder.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Tried what I found on this site, for instance using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(i)` and similar in the root `.htaccess`.

Comment: either `RewriteBase /i/` or `/i/index.php...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this, using a single rule in the root `.htaccess`. The root `.htaccess` is always going to get processed, so you might as well do it there with one rule. Otherwise it would be more complicated and the root would need modifying with an exception for `/i` anyway.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:i/)?index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(i/)?(.*)$ /$1index.php?img=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Using the `[QSA]` flag which is a better way to pass on any existing query string. `RewriteBase` is not needed. You perhaps don't need the directory check and it would be better for performance without it. The `index.php` check is there to improve performance by avoiding another file-system check after a successful rewrite.

**Update**

Sorry, I hadn't noticed that the parameter you are passing to `index.php` has a different name in the second case. These rules in root should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/i/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:i/)?index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)$ /i/index.php?img=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you here.. Using only this rule in root, instead of the one I have, the root `index.php` would not accept `?page=` requests any more. Adding what you wrote to after the last existing line in the root `.htaccess` and `/i/` will still accept `?page=` queries.. I'm sorry, not very strong on .htaccess at all

Comment: However, writing this into the /i/ htaccept and /i/ will also keep accepting `?page=` queries instead of the `?img=`

Comment: ..and using only what you wrote in root, the root page will no longer accept `?page=` queries but `/i/` will work as it should. Very confused, I'm sorry.